# Graphing Data Using Coreplot

Tags: ios, graph, nsarray, nsdictionary, core-plot

I'm using Coreplot and I need help plotting data on a graph.

I've populated an array called ***results*** with dictionary data. Output of it's contents are as follows (I've shortened data for simplicity purposes) -

```
{
   temperature = "5.0832667,5.2916833,4.6418246"; 
   windspeed = "2.333,2.521,2.021,1.833,1.292,1.167";
}
```

I'm having trouble getting this data to plot using the method ***numberForPlot***. Here is what I've done up until now. Below is an attempt to only plot the 'temperature' data -

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

        return [results valueForKey:@"temperature"];
{
```

I'm guessing it's to do with the way I create my dictionary, as they are strings, and NSNumbers are needed? As an additional note, here is the code that created the dictionary -

```
for(counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++) {

    [item setObject:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[node childAtIndex:counter] name]];

}

[results addObject:item];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been trying to get this working for several days now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each plot type uses different "fields" to request the plot data. For example, a scatterplot uses `CPTScatterPlotFieldX` to request x-values and `CPTScatterPlotFieldY` to request y-values.

The `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:` method tells Core Plot how many data points are available for the plot. The `-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:` method will be called once with each field value for each index in the range 0 through (n - 1).

There are a lot of example apps included with Core Plot. Look at any of them to see how to set up the datasource.